# How to convert a list of Strings to a list of tuples? (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of Strings: students, their grade in a certain course, course name. I need to convert each String inside the list to a tuple since it holds both Strings and Integers.

["PHL 220 A 3 Ada Lovelace A", "PHL 220 A 3 Grace Hopper C","THE 105 A 3 Grace Hopper B+"]

to

[("PHL",220,"A",3,"Lovelace, Ada",4.0), ("THE",105,"A",3,"Hopper, Grace",3.33)]

I tried this, but it does not work.

```
listToTuples :: [[String]] -> [(String | Integer)]
    listToTuples = map listToTuples
```

I am very new to Haskell, so the syntax is very confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work"? Provide error message.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors in your provided attempt. Luckily, these errors are mostly syntactical, and you are approaching the problem correctly.

Let’s go line by line:

```hs
listToTuples :: [[String]] -> [(String | Integer)]
```

This is almost correct, but:

- You have specified the input type to be `[[String]]` — that is, a list of list of strings. However, your input is actually a list of strings — that is, `[String]`.
- `(String | Integer)` is not correct Haskell syntax. Correct syntax is `(String, Integer)`. Additionally, your output type is actually a tuple of a string, an integer, a string, an integer, a string, and an integer, which translates to `(String, Int, String, Int, String, Int)`. (You *can* use `Integer` if you want, but it’s not required; if you’re interested, search for the difference between `Int` and `Integer` in Haskell.)

Putting these together, you get:

```hs
listToTuples :: [String] -> [(String, Int, String, Int, String, Int)]
```

That is, `listToTuples`, given a list of strings, will return a list of tuples. That sounds about right now!

Now, onto the next line:

```hs
    listToTuples = map listToTuples
```

You have two more mistakes here:

- Don’t indent it! If you indent this line, Haskell will interpret it as a continuation of the previous line, which this shouldn’t be. (For more information on Haskell indentation, refer to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).
- You are defining `listToTuples` in terms of `listToTuples`. This cannot possibly do anything! When the compiler tries to run your code, it will run into an infinite loop, where in order to run `listToTuples`, it will try to run `listToTuples` on every element on the list, which in term means it has to run `listToTuples` on every element of *those*, meaning…

Luckily, you are doing one thing right: you are using `map`! As you have noticed, `map` is exactly the right tool for this problem. So a solution would look like the following:

```hs
listToTuples :: [String] -> [(String, Int, String, Int, String, Int)]
listToTuples = map _
```

But with `_` replaced with a function converting a `String` to a `(String, Int, String, Int, String, Int)`. I will leave it to you to figure out what that function could be. (Hint: Use recursion to find all the bits between spaces, then use `read` to convert the strings to numbers.)